# Why I can't define a DOM element as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working on a form and wanted to use Javascript to output the form input.

So I have following script:

```
<script>
function showName() {
  var box = document.getElementById("lorem").value;

  console.log(box); 
}

showName(); 
</script> `
```

The code above works really well but I wanted the `var box = document.getElementById("lorem").value;` to be a global variable so that I can use it in other functions without re-declaring it.

So when I have this it doesn't output anything:
`

```
<script>
//Declared outside the function
var box = document.getElementById("lorem").value;

function showName() {
  console.log(box); 
}

showName(); 
</script>
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Dev console? If not, does `input#lorem` has any initial value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same. it is not a problem. if you are still getting the null error, I would suggest to add the script at the end of the document or enclose it in a `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` block like below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
var box = document.getElementById("lorem").value;
function showName() {


console.log(box); 

     }
showName(); 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="hai" id="lorem"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `box` is the initial value of your `lorem` element when you declare it. What you probably want is this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('lorem');

function showName() {
    console.log(box.value); // <-- get the current value
}

// Outputs the current value, initially it will be empty
// of course, until you change your input and call the 
// function again
showName();
```

Edit: the DOM needs to be loaded for this to work so make sure to put your script tags last in your `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

You can either put the script all the way at the end before you close the `<body>` tag, or do as @jafarbtech suggested and add an event listener to wait for the DOM content to load.

Comment: How do I add an event listener?

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded to get some more information on how to wait for the DOM to load.

Comment: The problem is that I wanted to make the function trigger "onclick"